# Convert CASE expression in SQL to derived column in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

```
CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('%', '{FixedARMRateReductionLimit}') > 0 THEN
            CAST(SUBSTRING('{FixedARMRateReductionLimit}', 0, 
               CHARINDEX('%', '{FixedARMRateReductionLimit}')) as decimal)/100
        WHEN '{FixedARMRateReductionLimit}' = 'Weekly PMMS Rate' THEN
            PARAM_VAL_TXT
        ELSE
            .02
    END
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: The provided code doesn't seem accurate. Has it been copied from some data access layer? `CHARINDEX('%', '{FixedARMRateReductionLimit}')` will always evaluate to 0 as the value of the second parameter never changes.

Comment: Previous account was [user1169594](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1169594/user1169594)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The moral of the following story is that just because you *can* do something in SSIS, it's not always a good idea.

Case in point, this query. It would be far more efficient to use the existing sql logic to generate the final value than using derived columns or a script task in SSIS (not to mention the waste of pipeline memory, CPU, etc)

### Source query

I used the following as a source query.

```
SELECT '50%' AS FixedARMRateReductionLimit, .1 AS PARAM_VAL_TXT
UNION ALL  SELECT 'Weekly PMMS Rate' AS FixedARMRateReductionLimit, .3 AS PARAM_VAL_TXT
UNION ALL  SELECT 'Frack',  .5
```

### Find Percent Position

Determine whether a percentage symbol exists in the column. This creates an column called `PercentPosition`

```
FINDSTRING(FixedARMRateReductionLimit, "%",1)
```

### Check for rate text

It should be sufficient to do a simple comparison as the first expression shows but I was having issues with it. I assume it's a [string conversion/comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138047.aspx) issue (see first Note). Rather than diddle with getting a boolean value, I used findstring to generate the ordinal position.

```
FixedARMRateReductionLimit == "'Weekly PMMS Rate"
FINDSTRING(FixedARMRateReductionLimit,"Weekly PMMS Rate",1)
```

### Derive Output

Enjoy the double usage of the [Ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138047.aspx).

```
(RateTextPosition > 0) ? (PARAM_VAL_TXT) : (PercentPosition == 0) ? .2 : ((DT_NUMERIC, 18,2) SUBSTRING(FixedARMRateReductionLimit,1,PercentPosition - 1))/100
```

You could have simplified some of this in a script task but I'd just do the logic in the source.

Answer (score 1):

This is just to show how the expression should be constructed in the derived transformation. I wouldn't suggest doing it this way since it is very hard to maintain.

Refer [@billinkc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181965/billinkc) answer to this question [**Convert CASE expression in SQL to derived column in SSIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608214/756519)

Here is how the expression should be written in Derived transformation.

```
(FINDSTRING(FixedARMRateReductionLimit,"%",1) > 1) ? ((DT_NUMERIC,5,2)SUBSTRING(FixedARMRateReductionLimit,1,FINDSTRING(FixedARMRateReductionLimit,"%",1) - 1)) : (FixedARMRateReductionLimit == "Weekly PMMS Rate" ? (0.35) : (0.02))
```

Formatted version of the expression.

```
(FINDSTRING(FixedARMRateReductionLimit,"%",1) > 1) 
    ?   (
            (DT_NUMERIC,5,2) 
                SUBSTRING(  FixedARMRateReductionLimit, 
                            1, 
                            FINDSTRING(FixedARMRateReductionLimit, "%", 1) - 1
                          )
        ) 
    :   FixedARMRateReductionLimit == "Weekly PMMS Rate" 
            ? (0.35) 
            : (0.02))
```

Sample data used:

```
SELECT c1 AS FixedARMRateReductionLimit
FROM
(
            SELECT '2.00%'              AS c1 
    UNION   SELECT '13.95%'             AS c1 
    UNION   SELECT '%52.00%'            AS c1 
    UNION   SELECT '%%'                 AS c1 
    UNION   SELECT '85.%42%'            AS c1 
    UNION   SELECT 'Weekly PMMS Rate'   AS c1 
    UNION   SELECT 'Monthly PMMS Rate' 
) T1
```

Output of derived transformation when viewed in data viewer:

[image: Output]

Comment: Good answer. However, it might be more convenient and developer-friendly to move such "complex" transformations to a Script transformation.