# How to convert below SQL Expression into derived column in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert CASE expression in SQL to derived column in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605540/convert-case-expression-in-sql-to-derived-column-in-ssis)

```
(CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('%', 'FixedARMRateReductionLimit') > 0 THEN
            CAST(SUBSTRING('FixedARMRateReductionLimit', 0, CHARINDEX('%', 'FixedARMRateReductionLimit')) as decimal)/100
        WHEN 'FixedARMRateReductionLimit' = 'Weekly PMMS Rate' THEN
        0.35 else 0.02 end ) as fixedarmratereductionlimit
```

some one can help me out plzz